# Target 'server' could not be found in project 'frontend'

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular 6 and trying to build application Server Side Rendering from several days.

I am continuously facing an error as below

```
    Target 'server' could not be found in project 'i18n'.
Error: Target 'server' could not be found in project 'i18n'.
    at Architect._getProjectTarget (/home/sada/Downloads/i18n/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect-legacy.js:111:19)
    at Architect.getBuilderConfiguration (/home/sada/Downloads/i18n/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect-legacy.js:118:29)
    at RunCommand.runSingleTarget (/home/sada/Downloads/i18n/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:160:45)
    at RunCommand.runArchitectTarget (/home/sada/Downloads/i18n/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:201:35)
    at RunCommand.run (/home/sada/Downloads/i18n/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/run-impl.js:14:25)
    at RunCommand.validateAndRun (/home/sada/Downloads/i18n/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:124:31)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build:client-and-server-bundles-i18n"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! i18n@1.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles-i18n: `ng run i18n:build:production-en && ng run i18n:build:production-fr && ng run i18n:server:production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the i18n@1.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles-i18n script 'ng run i18n:build:production-en && ng run i18n:build:production-fr && ng run i18n:server:production'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the i18n package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ng run i18n:build:production-en && ng run i18n:build:production-fr && ng run i18n:server:production
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs i18n
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls i18n
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/sada/Downloads/i18n/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build:i18n-ssr"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! i18n@1.0.0 build:i18n-ssr: `npm run build:client-and-server-bundles-i18n && npm run compile:server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the i18n@1.0.0 build:i18n-ssr script 'npm run build:client-and-server-bundles-i18n && npm run compile:server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the i18n package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build:client-and-server-bundles-i18n && npm run compile:server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs i18n
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls i18n
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/sada/Downloads/i18n/src/npm-debug.log
```

Since, my project name is 'frontend' and I am executing commands like below, after following full document describe on https://angular-templates.io/tutorials/about/angular-internationalization-i18n-multi-language-app

```
npm run build:i18n-ssr && npm run serve:ssr
```

I was able to do this and successfully run server side rendering on Angular 5. But it is not working on Angular 6 and I have followed the changes done in Angular 6 too.

Is that any issue in Angular 6? can anyone help me out.

Comment: How did you fix it?